# Determine CSS applied to JavaScript created element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools, x-editable

I wish to use x-editable and bootstrap-datetimepicker on the same page, but not on the same element.  When doing so, however, the css required for x-editable (`bootstrap-editable.css`) corrupts bootstrap-datetimepicker, and it looks like the first image below instead of the desired second image.  Note that x-editable's JavaScript has not even been included on the page, thus it must be just the `bootstrap-editable.css`.

[image]
[image]

To troubleshoot, I used Chrome's and Firefox's inspector to see what CSS is applied, however, when drilling down in the element tree, the JavaScript generated `div.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget` automatically closes which prevent's the Chrome dev-tools from being able to view the CSS which is applied to it.

How can the CSS which is applied to this element be determined so that some sort of fix be created?

[image]
https://jsbin.com/yanawuv

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" />
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.47/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As another solution, it is possible configure date picker to stay open after a blur event using `debug: true`.  Still would be nice to have a generic approach for using inspector to inspect such elements.

Comment: I usually set mouse or script event breakpoints in devtools -> sources -> "Event listener breakpoints" subpanel, then switch to the elements panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm.  Thanks.  As a workaround for my specific problem, `.datepicker > div {display: block;}` works.